# ios random crash debugging - help interpreting console info

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, console

I am getting the following report in the console when my app crashes randomly. It seems to happen on different screens of the app but i've added an example below. I'm not quite sure where to start in fixing this so any help or suggestions you can give would be brilliant! Thanks :-)

```
Dec  1 10:27:41 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay:                 Disabling autoplay for pause
Dec  1 10:27:41 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
Dec  1 10:27:41 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
Dec  1 10:27:41 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
Dec  1 10:27:41 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
Dec  1 10:27:41 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
Dec  1 10:27:41 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
Dec  1 10:27:41 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
Dec  1 10:27:41 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
Dec  1 10:27:41 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
Dec  1 10:27:41 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 1
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: This is my variable Moonshine
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad Moonshine2[4171] <Warning>: i'm moon
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad UserEventAgent[13] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x55e7][4132]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x55e7]) Exited: Killed: 9
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0xccd5][4130]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0xccd5]) Exited: Killed: 9
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.tccd[4133]) <Notice>: (com.apple.tccd) Exited: Killed: 9
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.TextInput.kbd[4144]) <Notice>: (com.apple.TextInput.kbd) Exited: Killed: 9
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.Moonshine2[0x74c9][4171]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.Moonshine2[0x74c9]) Exited: Killed: 9
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad backboardd[690] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x55e7]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad backboardd[690] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0xccd5]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Dec  1 10:27:42 Olivias-iPad backboardd[690] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.Moonshine2[0x74c9]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Dec  1 10:27:43 Olivias-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[4176] Builtin profile: MobileMail (sandbox)
Dec  1 10:27:44 Olivias-iPad ReportCrash[4175] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Dec  1 10:27:44 Olivias-iPad ReportCrash[4175] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2012-12-01-102744.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Dec  1 10:27:48 Olivias-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[4182] Builtin profile: syncdefaultsd (sandbox)
```

Comment: When Mail, Phone and your app are being killed subsequently, that generally means your application is eating up memory.

Comment: You seem to use too much memory, have you tried to profile your app with Instruments allocation inspector ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've just profiled the app with instruments allocation inspector. Look at the results (created and still living), i can see that the more the app is used, the more live and overall bytes increases. It seems from the results that as the user moves through the app, views that are removed are somehow kept in memory. Does that make sense? Do you have any suggestions as to what i can do to make sure they are released from memory? I am using:

Comment: FourthViewController *aFourthView = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthView" bundle:nil];
    [self setFourthViewController:aFourthView];
    [aFourthView release]; 
    [thirdViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window setRootViewController:fourthViewController];
    [thirdViewController release];
    thirdViewController = nil;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, it is possible that thirdViewController wasn't actually retained properly, but it stayed in memory from being retained by window (or so it would seem from the way you are using window).

Also, the way you are using this, it would perhaps be better architected to use a robust object that is built for this purpose, like UITabController.  It is possible to use it without it ever displaying anywhere, and you can swap out view controllers programmatically.  If that is not a good fit, then surely UINavigationController would be.  There is no need to reinvent the wheel.  Cheers.

Comment: Think this may be the case. I have done some work in converting the project to ARC in order to manage memory but what i am finding is that views are retained in memory. I have a UINavigationController. My app runs only in landscape left orientation. When i use  [window setRootViewController:viewController]; on load and then   [self.window addSubview:[finalViewController view]]; the new view is  displayed in portrait - if i rotate it to landscape left with code when i load it in, then all kinds of other random issues come up.

Comment: If instead of addSubview i use [self.viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window setRootViewController:finalViewController];viewController = nil; rotation is ok but views are not released and i have a memory issue with the app and it crashes eventually. Any thoughts would be awesome - appreciate i'm probably missing something fairly basic here.

Comment: I found that i was able to fix this by adding in    [viewController viewDidUnload];